# how do i only populate cells that has the same values in python from a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

I'm having a little trouble with my code, what I want to do is only populate the output to be of a certain value, meaning if I have a column which we shall label A and below column A has names ranging from A to D and I only want to print names starting with C, the problem I'm having is I'm generating all the names and not separating the names beginning with C from the rest.

so the code I've got is

```
import pandas as pd

nm = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
nm.sort_values("First_Name", axis=0, ascending=False, inplace=True, na_position='last')
nm.filter(like='C')

print(nm[['First_Name']])
```

and the `filter` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think that I'm tracking. But if you can add a simple df as an placeholder for your csv, we can more quickly get at the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do with the names but here is some code that selects the strings beginning with a certain letter and prints them out.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['betty', 'chris', 'steve', 'carly']})

letter = 'c'

print(df.loc[df['Names'].str.startswith(letter)])
```

Output:

```
Names
1  chris
3  carly
```